# JNI Utilities Library

Tags: java

If anyone has ever used or experimented with JNI, they will know that they have to jump through many hoops to try and make any progress.

First you have to compile your class, then you have to create the header, then you have to create your make file then you need to update your `java.library.path` which never works and constantly complains about `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`, not to mention integrating with Maven or your own IDE of choice.

It would be really useful if there was a JNIUtils dependency that I could just pass my `.c` file to and let it handle the paths and compilation so that you can just execute the native methods and not constantly bother with everything else.